# Can a plural possessive pronoun be used for “side”?

Tags: grammaticality

Be the following paragraph:

*Finally, the storm ended. Then, the two groups of men reached the centre of the field with their goods to trade. After they did it, **each side** took what was **theirs** and went back.*

Is it correct to use “theirs” in the third sentence?

Furthermore, is there some difference between British and American English in this regard?

I will appreciate your help.

P.S.: Perhaps further clarification of the context is needed. The two groups are made up of men of different nationalities, speaking different languages, and armed.

Comment: "Theirs" is fine - "each side" seems like an odd choice, though, unless there's some missing context to the nature of the two groups.

Comment: In AmE, we'd probably do a rewrite for agreement. You could probably get away with *both sides took what was theirs*. Your *it* in *after they did it* needs an antecedent, or change that to *after they traded...*  Maybe: *After they traded, each side retreated with its new goods.*

Comment: Where is this "plural possessive"? *Theirs* isn't always plural. Pick someone on the street, point at your own head and then point at theirs. Where is this "plural"? There is not one. Or do you mean these people as a group versus those people as a group?

Comment: @tchrist: In spoken English (and more frequently in written—even formal written), one would virtually always say "theirs" lest one sound peculiar. However, formally, it's "Pick someone on the street, point at your head, and then point at his or hers."

Comment: @TinfoilHat "Formally" it is rude to box someone you don't even know into "his or hers".  :) What if they are one of those nonbinary people who finds your assumption about them to be pushy and  offensive? No, *theirs* is the safe bet.

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, I agree, that is a safe bet. Formal English style guides are slowly coming around to accepting the singular *they.* But for now, most would suggest you write yourself out of the situation.